# montar url para abrir nova aba com parametros passados por onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

Como fazer uma função para tratar parametros passados no `onclick` para montar uma *URL* e abri-la em nova aba? Exemplo:

```
<button onclick="javascript:parent.funcao1('TESTE','ABCD', 'eydub21lJzonam9hbycsJ2lkYWRlJzogJzI5J30=');">TESTE</button>
```

parte dos dados que preciso estão em base64 no parametro: `eydub21lJzonam9hbycsJ2lkYWRlJzogJzI5J30=" que são {'nome':'joao','idade':'29'}`

exemplo *URL* para montar: `www.teste.com/pesquisa.php?nome='joao'&idade='29'&segmento='ABCD'`

A URL montada pode ser aberta num `iframe`, em nova `div`, ou nova aba.
Obs: Não posso alterar nada no `button` pois é puxado de um *banco de dados* nessa formatação.
Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o método [`.atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob) para decodificar o base64, você pode converter o resultado em objeto JSON e pegar os dados `nome` e `idade`.

Recebendo os parâmetros na função, você consegue montar uma URL e abrir em uma nova janela com `window.open`:

```
function funcao1(dom,seg,par){
   var par = atob(par).replace(/'/g,"\""); // substituo aspas simples por aspas duplas para o JSON
   par = JSON.parse(par); // crio o JSON
   par = "nome="+par.nome+"&idade="+par.idade; // monto a variável par com o nome e idade
   var url_ = "http://www."+dom.toLowerCase()+".com/pesquisa.php?"+par+"&segmento="+seg;
   window.open(url_,"_blank","..."); // abre em nova janela
}
```

Como o snippet aqui não abre popup, o resultado da variável `url_` na função acima será:

```
http://www.teste.com/pesquisa.php?nome=joao&idade=29&segmento=ABCD
```

> **Obs.:** onde tem `"..."` no `window.open`, você pode definir as propriedades da janela ([veja as opções aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)).

Comment: atendeu perfeitamente o que precisei, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

tem algum jeito de receber os parametros estando o link em um iframe externo?
no mesmo servidor faz exatamente o que preciso, ja funcionando com a ajuda do dvd.

função esta assim:

```
         function funcao1(dom,seg,par){
        var converter = atob(par); // decodifica base64
        var decodif_url = decodeURIComponent(converter); // decodifica uri
        var parx = JSON.parse(decodif_url); 
        var parx = parx.nome; 
        var parx = btoa(parx); // recolocar apenas nome em base64 para URL
        var url_ = "http://www."+dom.toLowerCase()+".com/pesquisa.php?"+parx+"&segmento="+par;
        window.open(url_,"_blank"); // abre em nova guia
        }
```

link no iframe servidor EXTERNO esta assim:

```
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:parent.funcao1('TESTE','ABCD', 'JTdCJTIybm9tZSUyMiUzQSUyMmpvYW8lMjIlMkMlMjJpZGFkZSUyMiUzQSUyMjM3JTIyJTdE');">
                          <nobr>TESTE</nobr>
                       </a>
```